# Why does /dev/mmcblk0p2 work when PARTUUID doesn't?

Tags: raspbian, boot, root, cmdline.txt

**Goal**

Hi my PI keeps rebooting after I added two lines to the rc.local file. Now i am trying to log into the boot shell and edit those two lines out.

**Problem**

I added `init=/bin/bash` to the cmdline.txt and it looks like the following:

```
 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=PARTUUID=61f5b861-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline 
fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles init=/bin/bash
```

I then can successfully log into the boot shell and type at the command line. However, whenever I've tried the following commands to remount the file system as read/write:

```
mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

it gave an error: `mount: can't find PARTUUID=61f5b861-02`

Then after I read some posts on the forum, I changed the root in my cmdline.txt to the following:

```
 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline 
fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles init=/bin/bash
```

And then i ran the command: `mount: mount point /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`
It just worked...

**Question**

Can somebody explain what happened? This doesn't seem to be the solution for anybody else.

Reference:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1284212

[How do I start up in safemode?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/how-do-i-start-up-in-safemode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root=` field from `cmdline.txt` specifies to the kernel where the partition with the root filesystem is.  There are a few ways that can be specified.  The one that is generally preferred in the linux world is `UUID` or `PARTUUID`, because it depends on a fixed identifier assigned to the partition as opposed to the other commonplace method, a `/dev` node, which is less predictable on systems that have various sorts of storage attached the configuration of which may change, meaning the associated `/dev` node would then change, whereas the UUID would not.

There's a bit of a complication with `PARTUUID`, though, which is really intended for use on GPT disks, but is also something that Windows systems won't get wrong when dealing with `ext4` partitions, for a further explanation:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95436/5538

Anyway, when you copy a partition, unlike the UUID, the PARTUUID doesn't go with it, which is why they can get lost.  Conversely, if you copy `cmdline.txt` around, you'll end up with a mismatch.

However, in the context of a normal 2 partition Rpi SD card, `/dev/mmcblk0p2` is unequivocal: It means the second partition on the first SD block device.

You can check the PARTUUID on a running system with:

```
blkid /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Chances are it isn't `61f5b861-02`.

Comment: Linux supports PARTUUID for MBR partitions, but this is not fixed and is just a positional notation for the partition on the MBR disk.
The format is SSSSSSSS-PP, where SSSSSSSS is a 32-bit MBR disk signature (stored in the MBR label-id field), and PP is a partition number. PARTUUID creates more problems than it solves on the Pi as SD Cards are easily, and commonly moved/duplicated.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it is derived from a value in the MBR is why you can deduce it without having (or being able) to read any partition data, which is where a normal UUID is (permanently labelled in the fs).  The other issue on the Pi cards is vfat parititions can't be labelled with a UUID, so PARTUUID *seems* like a smart choice, except that: 1) You could use `root=UUID` even if the first partition doesn't have one, 2) Much less problematic in context would be just using the `/dev` node.